# Publishing CKAN data in an ISO-19115 format

Tags: metadata, publish, iso, ckan

I have a CKAN instance : https://rsg.pml.ac.uk/ckan/ and I am looking for a way to get the data in an ISO-19115 standard format.

Some of the other things that I have tried include:

**pycsw** can only publish data that is harvested from elsewhere

**PublicaMundi**; I could not find any documentation on how to use it, and found no evidence of it in the CKAN instance when I installed it

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I should think your data publishers would supply the records in ISO format. 450 out of 468 of your datasets are in WMS format suggesting they originate on GIS servers which tend to come with ISO records. And the publishers of the data come from scientific organizations who are usual sort of people to produce ISO records. I know for example that CEH produce (ISO-compatible) GEMINI2 records: https://catalogue.ceh.ac.uk/documents/gemini/waf/

Comment: @D Read The ISOs that are provided by the publishers only contain partial records, we are hoping to move the system over to CKAN so that more information is contained. We are looking to take the data from CKAN because it has had additional information (such as  organization information and dataset descriptions) added to it. We then want publishers to publish the data on CKAN instead of the THREDDs instance that we have at the moment

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to write a small extension that includes a new route and template. This is how CKAN *used to* produce RDF and n3 output:
https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/ckan-2.4.1/ckan/templates/package/read.n3

A more elegant way, already set up as an extension (but it does far more), can be found here:
https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-dcat