# Is it possible to publish data from my CKAN in CSW standard

Tags: ckan

I want to expose all my data from my Ckan database in CSW format so that other catalog can use it.

The only tool I found is [pycsw](https://pycsw.org/).
It has CKAN integration and it is documented [here](https://docs.ckan.org/projects/ckanext-spatial/en/latest/csw.html). But ckan-pycsw documentation says:

> Remember, only datasets that were harvested with the Spatial
> Harvesters can currently be exposed via pycsw.

Is there any way that enables me to expose my data that i already have in CKAN in CSW standard? Last time this was mentioned was [7 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717718/publishing-ckan-data-in-an-iso-19115-format), but i hope that someone found solution for it in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you need to implement your own method to import data into pycsw.

There is a `ckan_pycsw.py` tool provided by `ckanext-spatial`, but it is not maintained (it uses some API that have been deprecated since CKAN 2.0: https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-spatial/issues/298). It can give you an idea about how to load data in pycsw from CKAN: https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-spatial/blob/master/bin/ckan_pycsw.py.

You can use https://geopython.github.io/pygeometa/ or https://github.com/antarctica/metadata-library to generate the XML that should then be imported into PyCSW.

Here is my code which achieves that, based on a custom CKAN schema: https://github.com/COATnor/coat2pycsw.